# How to validate form both on submit and keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My form validates on keyup, but when I try to validate it on submit too I just can't think what to do.

This is my HTML:

```
   <form action="#" method="post">                      
        <section class="col">   

            <section class="row">                   
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" class="field validate-field valid-name" />                    
            </section>

            <section class="row">                   
                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" class="field validate-field valid-mail" />                  
            </section>

            <section class="row">                   
                <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
                <input type="text" name="phone" value="" id="phone" class="field validate-field valid-phone" />                     
            </section>                  
        </section>

        <section class="col">               
            <label for="message">Message</label>
            <textarea class="field validate-field valid-text" name="message" id="message-field"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
        </section>
   </form>
```

JS:

```
function validate( field ){
    var value = field.val();
    var to_label = field.parent().find('label');
    var error = false;
    var error_message = '';

    to_label.find('span').remove();

    if ( field.hasClass('validate-field') && value == '' ) {
        error = true;
        error_message = 'Empty Field';  
    } else if ( field.hasClass('valid-name') && valid_name(value) == false ) {
        error = true;
        error_message = 'Name must consist characters only';
    } else if ( field.hasClass('valid-mail') && valid_email(value) == false ) {
        error = true;
        error_message = 'Invalid Email';
    } else if ( field.hasClass('valid-phone') && valid_phone(value) == false ) {
        error = true;
        error_message = 'Your phone must be digits only';
    };

    if ( error == true ) {
        to_label.append('<span>'+ error_message +'</span>');
    }
};


$('.validate-field').live('keyup', function(){
    validate( $(this) );
});

function valid_name(value){
    var valid = /^([a-zA-Z_\.\-\+])+$/;
    return valid.test(value);
};

function valid_email(value){
    var valid = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    return valid.test(value);
};

function valid_phone(value){
    var valid = /^[0-9-+]+$/;
    return valid.test(value);
```

};

And I have to add something like this:

```
$('form').live('submit', function(){

    if ( "...validated..." ) {  
        $.post('send.php', $('form').serialize(), function(){
            alert('sent to PHP.');
        })  
    };
    return false;
});
```

What should be in the submit function?

I have tried:

```
$('form').live('submit', function(){

    var valid = validate( $('.field') )

    if ( valid  == true ) { 
        $.post('send.php', $('form').serialize(), function(){
            alert('sent to PHP.');
        })  
    };
    return false;
});
```

But this validates all the forms with all the validation (e-mail, phone ...). I have tried in `validation()` function to add `if (error == false){ return: true }`, then in **submit function** ran `validation()` and added `if ( validation() == true ){ .. to send php ..}`. That didn't work too. What I need to do ?

Comment: why don't you use validation plugins... you can find lots of validation plugins that does everything that you have mentioned here

Comment: your validate function is not returning true/false. Inside `if ( error == true ) {` you need to add `return false;`

Comment: I don't use plugins cause that is exercise and I have to make it work that way

Comment: Here is how can be done: http://jsfiddle.net/mgechev/rb7kG/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can validate the whole form by:

```
function validateAll() {
    var valid = true;
    $('form').find('.validate-field').each(function (i, e) {
        if (!validate($(this))) {
           valid = false;
            return;
        }
    });
    return valid;
}

function validate( field ){
    var value = field.val();
    var to_label = field.parent().find('label');
    var error = false;
    var error_message = '';

    to_label.find('span').remove();

    if ( field.hasClass('validate-field') && value == '' ) {
        error = true;
        error_message = 'Empty Field';  
    } else if ( field.hasClass('valid-name') && valid_name(value) == false ) {
        error = true;
        error_message = 'Name must consist characters only';
    } else if ( field.hasClass('valid-mail') && valid_email(value) == false ) {
        error = true;
        error_message = 'Invalid Email';
    } else if ( field.hasClass('valid-phone') && valid_phone(value) == false ) {
        error = true;
        error_message = 'Your phone must be digits only';
    };

    if (error) {
        to_label.append('<span>'+ error_message +'</span>');
    }
    return !error;

};

$('form').live('submit', function(){

    if (validateAll()) {  
        $.post('send.php', $('form').serialize(), function(){
            alert('sent to PHP.');
        })  
    };
    return false;
});
```

That's the option which requires the smallest amount of refactoring, on my opinion.

Just let me explain you what the function `validateAll` does. It finds all fields with class `validate-field` and pass it as argument to the `validate` function. Because of the refactoring I made in `validate` it returns `false` if the field is not valid so when we call `validate` with specific input and it's invalid we just return false (the form is not valid).

Here is an example in [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgechev/rb7kG/4/).

For more advance validation I can recommend you validation plugins like: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation or [jqxValidator](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxvalidator/defaultfunctionality.htm?classic).

Comment: nope .. it sends the data to php anyway, no matter if the the fields are validater or not. EDIT: with the last correction you do to your core it worked :) Just I am not sure if I understand it :)

Comment: We walk through all inputs and check whether the current input is valid. If it is not we stop the input traversal and return false, otherwise return true.

Comment: Yes I got it ... just need some time to realize.. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done. Just add below code, it'll work

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var field = $(this).find('.validate-field');
    validate( field );
});
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r1webs/cFeCx/

Comment: it's just like the one way I've tried and I wrote it doesn't work